# Spring Data converter error on first page load, works fine afterwards

Tags: spring, exception, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring-data-mongodb dependency in my Spring MVC application. It was working fine till now but I needed to add a Class instance property to one of my domain objects. Since Mongo doesn't support persisting Class instances directly, I added custom converter for this case. I followed the instructions here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/mongo.core.html#mongo.custom-converters.writer

So my converters looks like:

```
public class ClassReadConverter implements Converter<DBObject, Class> {
    public Class convert(DBObject source){
        Class entityClass = null;
        try{
            entityClass = Class.forName((String) source.get("entityClass"));
        }catch (Exception e){ 
        }
        return entityClass;
    }
}

public class ClassWriteConverter implements Converter<Class, DBObject> {
    public DBObject convert(Class entityClass) {
        DBObject dbo = new BasicDBObject();
        dbo.put("entityClass", entityClass.getName());
        return dbo;
    }
}
```

I registered these converters using:

```
<mongo:mapping-converter>
    <mongo:custom-converters>
        <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="com.test.util.ClassReadConverter"/>
        </mongo:converter>
        <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="com.test.util.ClassWriteConverter"/>
        </mongo:converter>
    </mongo:custom-converters>
</mongo:mapping-converter>

<!-- MongoTemplate instance -->
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mappingConverter"/>
</bean>
```

Now the issue is that when the app starts and I load the first page in the app for the first time, I get an exception. If I reload/resubmit that page everything works fine. Every single page I access after that works without issues as well.

This is the write exception:

```
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.SecurityException: Can not make a java.lang.Class constructor accessible
at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible0(AccessibleObject.java:118)
at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:108)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtils.java:437)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PreferredConstructor.<init>(PreferredConstructor.java:54)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.buildPreferredConstructor(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:106)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.<init>(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:74)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.<init>(BasicPersistentEntity.java:73)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity.<init>(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:60)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(MongoMappingContext.java:74)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(MongoMappingContext.java:36)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:269)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:411)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:570)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:281)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:190)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:159)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:69)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:333)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeCollectionInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:517)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.createCollection(MappingMongoConverter.java:477)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writePropertyInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:408)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:376)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:363)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:195)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:363)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writePropertyInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:442)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:376)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:363)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:195)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:363)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:334)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.write(MappingMongoConverter.java:299)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.write(MappingMongoConverter.java:72)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doSave(MongoTemplate.java:804)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.save(MongoTemplate.java:750)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.save(SimpleMongoRepository.java:71)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:334)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:319)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at $Proxy51.save(Unknown Source)
at com.test.service.saveContent(ContentServiceImpl.java:42)
at com.test.web.controller.ContentController.create(ContentController.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Mar 7, 2013 5:50:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jersey-servlet threw exception
java.lang.SecurityException: Can not make a java.lang.Class constructor accessible
at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible0(AccessibleObject.java:118)
at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:108)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtils.java:437)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PreferredConstructor.<init>(PreferredConstructor.java:54)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.buildPreferredConstructor(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:106)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.<init>(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:74)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.<init>(BasicPersistentEntity.java:73)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity.<init>(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:60)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(MongoMappingContext.java:74)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(MongoMappingContext.java:36)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:269)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:411)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:570)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:281)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:190)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:159)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:69)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:333)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeCollectionInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:517)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.createCollection(MappingMongoConverter.java:477)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writePropertyInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:408)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:376)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:363)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:195)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:363)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writePropertyInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:442)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:376)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:363)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:195)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:363)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:334)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.write(MappingMongoConverter.java:299)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.write(MappingMongoConverter.java:72)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doSave(MongoTemplate.java:804)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.save(MongoTemplate.java:750)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.save(SimpleMongoRepository.java:71)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:334)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:319)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at $Proxy51.save(Unknown Source)
at com.test.service.ContentServiceImpl.saveContent(ContentServiceImpl.java:42)
at com.test.web.controller.ContentController.create(ContentController.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Read exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Can not make a java.lang.Class constructor accessible
at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible0(AccessibleObject.java:118)
at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:108)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtils.java:437)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PreferredConstructor.<init>(PreferredConstructor.java:54)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.buildPreferredConstructor(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:106)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.<init>(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:74)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.<init>(BasicPersistentEntity.java:73)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity.<init>(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:60)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(MongoMappingContext.java:74)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(MongoMappingContext.java:36)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:269)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:411)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:570)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:281)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:190)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:69)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:203)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readCollectionOrArray(MappingMongoConverter.java:746)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$100(MappingMongoConverter.java:72)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:954)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getValueInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:710)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:245)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:235)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:195)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:235)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:209)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:956)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getValueInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:710)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:245)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:235)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:195)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:235)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:209)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readCollectionOrArray(MappingMongoConverter.java:743)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$100(MappingMongoConverter.java:72)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:954)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getValueInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:710)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$2.doWithAssociation(MappingMongoConverter.java:254)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:207)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:251)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:209)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:173)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:169)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:72)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDbObjectCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:1820)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1503)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFindOne(MongoTemplate.java:1309)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findOne(MongoTemplate.java:489)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findOne(MongoTemplate.java:484)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery$SingleEntityExecution.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:202)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:90)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:313)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
```

Why do I get this issue only for one page and the first time only? Its like something is not instantiated and then suddenly its all fine. Any help is appreciated!!

I am using 1.1.1.RELEASE version and even tried using 1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to run your code with Spring Data MongoDB version 1.2.0.RELEASE and worked fine. Just to be clear - my document class is:

```java
@Document
public class User {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private String name;
    private Class clazz;

    public User(String name) {
        this.id = new ObjectId();
        this.name = name;
        this.clazz = this.getClass();
    }
}
```

And it worked perfectly fine - i tried it with unit test only. Maybe it's fixed with new (1.2.0.RELEASE) version?

Comment: Do you run it on some weird JVM/application server?